# How to create github PRs from Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: github, jenkins-pipeline

I'd like to make a new git branch, add a commit, and then push to github. In addition, it would be great to create a PR for that branch straight from Jenkins job.

Has anyone done it yet? The part I'm struggling is how to create a PR. For creating a branch and commit, I'm running regular git commands in the shell.

Thanks, N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want the [pipeline multi branch plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Multibranch+Plugin) there's a blog here https://jenkins.io/blog/2015/12/03/pipeline-as-code-with-multibranch-workflows-in-jenkins/ that might help too.  We use this plugin on the fabric8 project and it works great.

**Correction**: I misread the question initially.  We use a [shared pipeline library](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) that contains reusable functions to make pull requests.  [This](https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8-pipeline-library/blob/master/vars/pushPomPropertyChangePR.groovy#L59) is an example where we make version update PRs on downstream repos once a release has finished.  The groovy code that interacts with the github api is [here](https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8-pipeline-library/blob/master/src/io/fabric8/Fabric8Commands.groovy#L333-L370)

Comment: This plugin deals with jenkins building multiple PRs, but it doesn't help with creating new branches/PRs directly from jenkins job (pipeline).

Comment: Ah sorry I misread the issue - we create PRs from within a pipeline with the help of a shared pipeline library.  For example we update downstream pom / npm versions once a release has finished and available https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8-pipeline-library/blob/master/vars/pushPomPropertyChangePR.groovy#L59 which in turn calls this groovy function https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8-pipeline-library/blob/master/src/io/fabric8/Fabric8Commands.groovy#L333.  Is this more in line with what you're after?

Comment: Nice! Can you please update your answer with this treasure trove of nice functions :)